# How to display text background color beyond text?

Tags: css

I have run into a problem, where background of a text field does not cover the whole element, but only extends as far as the text does. [An example](http://dijkstra.cs.ttu.ee/~t120377/maagilinematk/ask.html).

I'd like the background color to extend throughout the element. Like this:

[image]

Edit. I am interested in a CSS solution, which works with all screen sizes. Just writing *height: n px* would not work.

Comment: put a height on there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below, as I change **height:**, the background also changes:

[image]

```
div.text {
position: relative;
background-color: #DFDFDF;
opacity: 0.8;
padding-top: 8px;
padding-right: 52px;
padding-bottom: 8px;
padding-left: 12px;
font-family: arial;
text-align: justify;
font-size: 0.9em;
height: 150px; <--- work with this 656px seems perfect.
background-size: 100%;
}
```

Comment: That does it, but I'd prefer a solution where I didn't have to use px.  So that the design would work with any screen size.

Comment: I javascripted around the problem. Accepted your answer for the awesome graphics. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just changed `display:table` to `display:block` in class `middlearea` - and it now seems to work as you wanted it to.

**Edit**: And yes of course deleting `display` property at all will lead to the same result.

Comment: Confirmed. No matter what I do, I cannot make height of div with class `middlearea` more than 0 in Chrome. Will look into it further.

Comment: Ok damn the Chrome is all I can say about it, and I would recommend you not to use this old table-like display styles. Apparently, some browsers handle them differently, and it's easier to adjust normal block-like divs a little to get stable result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I fully understand your question, but maybe you could set a `min-height` property to your container, so that no matter how short the text is, it will always display a minimun height.

Comment: Whoops, totally right, although I think the problem may be he set it in %. When changed to px or em, it works.

Comment: Nopes. Not sure. Some other issue.